# How do I measure the pixel height of a svelte component?

Tags: svelte

I am trying to measure the height of a component and keep getting undefined. It works if I put an html container around the component but that doesn't seem like the correct solution to me.

Here's my svelte code:

```
<script lang='ts'>

import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import DataTable, {
    Head,
    Row,
    Cell,
  } from '@smui/data-table';

  let headElement;
  let headHeight = 0;



  const measureHead = () => {
    if(headElement) {
      headHeight = headElement.offsetHeight
    }
  }
  onMount(() => {
    measureHead();
    console.log("Height: ", headHeight) //Returns undefined
  })

</script>


<DataTable table$aria-label="User list" style="width: 100%;" >

    <Head bind:this={headElement}>
        <Row>
        <Cell style="width: 100%;">Title</Cell>
        <Cell>Type</Cell>
        <Cell numeric>Distance</Cell>
        </Row>
    </Head>
</DataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`offsetHeight` is not svelte specific property, it is a property of an element in JavaScript represents the height of the element, including vertical padding, borders, and the horizontal scrollbar (if present), but excluding the margin.

```
  let headElement:HTMLElement;
  let headHeight = 0;



  const measureHead = () => {
    if(headElement) {
      headHeight = headElement.offsetHeight
    }
  }
```

`headElement` must be bind to an element. if you do not want to use binding, you can use this:

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let headHeight = 0;

  onMount(() => {
    const head = document.querySelector('.head');
    if (head) {
      headHeight = head.offsetHeight;
    }
  });
</script>

<div class="head"></div>

<p>The head's height is {headHeight}px.</p>
```

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Can I get the component height without binding to an element?

Answer (score 2):

`Head` is a component, not an element, so that is what you get from `bind:this`.

You either need to bind a property that returns an underlying element, otherwise gain access to the element or use a wrapper.

It looks like the SMUI components generally export a [`getElement()` function](https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui/blob/120b9b8bff274ecaa202d4a72ce8f904d5c03c83/packages/data-table/src/Head.svelte#L100-L102), so  here you could try `getElement().offsetHeight` instead.